# Ctrl+Alt+F1 not working on vnc

Tags: linux, console, gui, vnc

I use a real vnc viewer to connect to my host machine. The host machine has Linux in the GUI mode. I would like to switch between the GUI and the console mode, however the key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> opens up my local graphics control panel. I tried using the Menu key <kbd>F8</kbd> as well but it is also not working. The same problem occurs for tigervnc as well.

Answer (score 3):

The `VNC` server is an X window server and it does not serve the text consoles. So, even if you send the `Ctrl-Alt-F1` combination (there are options at the viewers menu to send some special key combinations), it will not be treated as you expect.

Use an `ssh` or other kind of terminal connection to get terminal access.

Comment: Thanks Serge. However I would like to stick to vnc. Any other alternative?

Comment: you could open xterm window inside your remote X desktop